# Can we use java Stream to refactor this?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to **refactor** the following `for` loop using `Stream`s in Java 8?

Moving the state from the inside to outside while collecting the list for different sources?

```
Map<StateEnum, List<List<ThreadDo>>> stateDumpListMap = new HashMap<>();
for (ThreadDumpDo dumpDo : dumpDoList) {
    Map<StateEnum, List<ThreadDo>> stateDoListMap = getStateGroup(dumpDo);
    stateDoListMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
       stateDumpListMap.putIfAbsent(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>());
       stateDumpListMap.get(entry.getKey()).add(entry.getValue());
     });
}
```

Recently I tried several use cases but it just seems ugly to me.

I tried to use `stream().map()` to achieve that, but I failed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: dumpDoList.forEach(dumpDo -> { ... }) would work, but seriously don't use streams for the sake of using streams. They won't make your code more readable in every context and probably not in this context.

Comment: i think flatMap should be in your code!

Comment: @Synth Yes, you are right. But I think at least sometimes I should have a try to **refactor** so when I really need it, I can **smoothly** do it.

Comment: @YCF_L Just tested and you are right. Thank you ~

Comment: `for(ThreadDumpDo dumpDo : dumpDoList) getStateGroup(dumpDo) .forEach((k,v) -> stateDumpListMap.computeIfAbsent(k, x -> new ArrayList<>()) .add(v));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<StateEnum, List<List<ThreadDo>>> stateDumpListMap = dumpDoList.stream()
    .flatMap(dumpDo -> getStateGroup(dumpDo).entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        entry -> entry.getKey(),
        Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, using `collect` instead of `forEach` to generate the `Map`, and using `flatMap` to eliminate the `for` loop:

```
Map<StateEnum, List<List<ThreadDo>>> stateDumpListMap =
    dumpDoList.stream ()
              .flatMap (d->getStateGroup(d).entrySet().stream ())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         e -> {
                                            List<List<ThreadDo>> l = new ArrayList<>(); 
                                            l.add (e.getValue());
                                            return l;
                                         },
                                         (v1,v2)->{v1.addAll(v2);return v1;}));
```

Which, as Aominè commented, can be simplified to:

```
Map<StateEnum, List<List<ThreadDo>>> stateDumpListMap =
    dumpDoList.stream ()
              .flatMap (d->getStateGroup(d).entrySet().stream ())
              .collect(Collectors.toMap (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                         e -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(e.getValue())),
                                         (v1,v2)->{v1.addAll(v2);return v1;}));
```

Comment: This is really nice and generic code, I think for OP it suits best in case the toMap needs to be highly customizable.

Comment: The value mapper can be simplified to `e -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(e.getValue()))`

Comment: @Aominè thanks! I could have used `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList())` too.

Answer (score 1):

One more option, with `collect`:

```
Map<StateEnum, List<List<ThreadDo>>> stateDumpListMap = dumpDoList.stream()
    .map(this::getStateGroup)   // dumpDo mapped to stateDoListMap  ( Map<StateEnum, List<ThreadDo>> )
    .map(Map::entrySet)         // stream of sets of entries of stateDoListMap (Entry<StateEnum, List<ThreadDo>>)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)       // stream of entries of all stateDoListMaps 
    .collect(HashMap::new,      // collect to a new HashMap, types infered from the variable declaration
            (map, stateDoListMapEntry) -> map.computeIfAbsent(stateDoListMapEntry.getKey(), key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(stateDoListMapEntry.getValue()), // for each entry incoming from the stream, compute it if does not exist in the target map yet (create the top level list), then add List<ThreadDo> to it.
            Map::putAll);
```

The three-argument `collect` allows to specify exact implementation of the map it returns. It may or may not be necessary to have control over that - depending on what you need the map for.